# AGI STK Server alternative

Tags: spatial-statistics, satellite, software-recommendations, ground-control

AGI has a server product called [STK Server](https://www.agi.com/product-explorer/Default.aspx#productid=13--catid=0--capid=0--typeid=0--modelingid=0) that exposes REST services to perform satellite acquisition planning. However the cost is astronomical $200k+ (pun inteded). They also have STK components (DLLs) which will allow you to build the web services yourself but, this API is also expensive.

Does anyone know of any economical alternatives? Any actively maintained open source projects would be great.

I need either an API or web service (REST, SOAP, etc) which I can perform satellite feasibility analysis. For example: I give it a point, time, and satellites (or sensors) I'm interested in and it will give me the available ground swaths.

I found [eo-sps-library](https://code.google.com/p/eo-sps-library), but it doesn't look like anyone is maintaining it.